# why doesn't work correctly to fetch child data from parent(root) object in EFCore by DDD-aggregation pattern via customize DbContext and Repository

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have `Biller`, `BillerReference`, `BillerSetting` DbSet.
`BillerReference` and `BillerSetting` has `BillerId` as foreign key relation.

This is Biller.cs

```
public class Biller : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual decimal? Amount {get;set;}

    public virtual List<BillerReference> BillerReferences {get;set;}

    public virtual List<BillerSetting> BillerSettings {get;set;}
}
```

BillerReference.cs

```
public class BillerReference : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int? BillerId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual string Key {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual string Value {get;set;}
}
```

BillerSetting.cs

```
public class BillerSetting : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [Required]
    public virtual int? BillerId {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual string URL {get;set;}
}
```

And then, I created BillerDbContext, which also include the BillerReference DbSet and BillerSetting DbSet.
And then, I created BillerRepository.
And then, I created BillerServiceAppService class in Application Layer.
When I call GetBiller(int Id) function as below

```
public async Task<BillerForEdit> GetBiller(int Id)
{
    var biller = _billerRepo.GetAll()
        .Include(x => x.BillerReferences)
        .Include(x => x.BillerSettings)
        .where(x => x.Id==Id);
    //convert and assign data by ObjectMapper here !
    //but, when got Biller object, BillerReferences and BillerSettings are Count=0!
```

In above function, I got `Biller`, but this is no `BillerReferences` and `BillerSetting`.

Please help me :D

Comment: can you share the declaration for `GetAll` function? what does it return?

Comment: Based on your code, it seems you are using `aspnetboilerplate`, it should work with `            var biller = _billerRepo.GetAll()
                .Include(x => x.BillerReferences)
                .Include(x => x.BillerSettings)
                .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
                .ToList();` I suggest you check whether Biller Id with the passed value exists in `BillerReferences` and `BillerSettings` tables. Before converting and assigning, did you call `ToList()` to retrive database?

Comment: Thanks so much Neville Nazerane and Edward ! :D I'll try to solve :D

Comment: I tried adding .ToList(), but it not work! Still getting BillerReferences and BillerSettings with Count=0!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `GetAll` function gets all by using something like `context.Billers.ToList()`. The two list runs a select query and calls the data. Running include after this will not connect to the database to fetch your `BillerReferences` or `BillerSetting`.

Based on your usage, your easiest solution is implementing your GetAll class like this:

```
public IQueryable<Billing> GetAll() => context.Billers;
```

Comment: note that this is unsafe. it is usually recommended to have a `Get(id)` function

Comment: Thanks so much Neville Nazerane ! I'll try to solve and then I'll reply that is OK or Not :D

Comment: I used GetAll() which is one of Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase<BillerDbContext, Biller, int>.GetAll()

Comment: I tested with SQL Query to get BillerReferences and BillerSettings by BillerId(FK) in their tables !

Comment: I created formerly Template(root) entity and TemplateDetails(child) entity and then I created AppService for this and it work correctly ! Why in this Biller doesn't work correctly ? :D

Comment: I also tried with ICollection<T> instead of List<T> !

Comment: @ThetPhyoAung Could you share us a project to reproduce your issue? I am wondering whether there is relation data in `BillerReferences` are not `Deleted`. In addition, I suggest you try to **upgrade the reference to latest version** for your project.

Comment: Thanks so much @Edward :D !! I'm so sorry for lately reply ! I found this stages(update and delete). Just now, I solving this feactures by updating and deleteing with their own repository(IRepository<BillerReference> , etc) :D

Comment: And now I solving above stage(BillerReference and BillerSetting are 0(ezero) count), by using original ProjectDbContext ! And, in AspNetZero framework is not easy and not OK if I trying to separate each own DbContext!!